# Why does Visual Studio 2013 Browser Link use long polling?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, signalr, browser-link

I understand that browserlink uses SignalR to create an open connection to Visual Studio 2013.  For an asp.net MVC application I am developing and testing in the latest firefox browser, the transport method used by the browser link connection is "longPolling".

I am curious why the transport method is not promoted to a WebSocket connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the the BrowserLink feature to support WebSockets, you should be using Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012. You can get more details about this from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21706524/413736) answer.